# Convert NVARCHAR to money value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert an NVARCHAR value to a money value with MsSQL.

I know I can use something like:

```
SELECT CONVERT(money, ValueColumn) FROM SomeTable
```

But the problem is when I have a value 4352,50, and I call the convert method, the value becomes 435250,00

What am I missing? I also tried CONVERT(money, ValueColumn, 2) but without any success.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please tell in which locale you are working. For me living in a , as decimal-separator land. Select displays all numbers wrong i.e. NLS modified. For me it would be perfectly OK. I would expect . as decimal separator (I'm programmer and no business man) and the result be displayed with decimal-, . To prevent those NLS-Disturbances I use select cast (CONVERT (money, '1.1') as varchar) to get the internal representation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SELECT CONVERT(money, REPLACE('4352,50', ',', '.'))`

Answer (score 2):

As you are working in ,- as-decimal-separator use this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(money, REPLACE(ValueColumn, ',', '.'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
DECLARE @ValueColumn NVARCHAR(20)

SELECT @ValueColumn = '4352.50'

SELECT CONVERT(money, @ValueColumn)
```

VS

```
DECLARE @ValueColumn NVARCHAR(20)

SELECT @ValueColumn = '4352,50'

SELECT CONVERT(money, @ValueColumn)
```

The comma is not being intepreted as the decimal point.

Comment: Ok but how can I use it in a query without hardcoding the values? Because it's a table with 160.000 rows...

Comment: You will have to use a replace on the columns first. Something like *REPLACE(@ValueColumn,',','.')*

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a hack but if the rest of your data is the same format

e.g 
`numbers , numbers ,`

```
Declare @Value nvarchar(50)

Set @Value = '4352,50,'

Select Convert(Money, Substring(@Value, 0, Charindex(',',@value)) + '.' + Substring(@Value, Charindex(',',@Value)+1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT TRY_PARSE('12.345,67' AS Money USING 'pt-BR')